# R proportional fitting optimization

Tags: r, optimization, data-fitting

any help on this is appreciated. I'm currently running a block of code that takes hours to run. I know the code is written inefficiently but I'm not good enough with R to know how to refine this. Please help make this run faster.

**About the code:**
The data set has a list of storeIDs, product category IDs [category], and inventory amounts at months end for each month in a quarter [vol1, vol2, vol3]

The categories are numerical Ids that get more specific as the numbers get longer. For example, categoryID 128 may be "Automobile rims" and category ID 1281 may be "Alloy automobile rims" and CategoryID 12811 may be " 18 inch, Alloy Automobile Rims"

The 3 digit categoryIDs are more accurate in volume count than the 4 digit CategoryIDs. So, I'm trying to proportionally fit the volume of the 4 digit codes to the 3 digit totals.

Another fun thing is that not all stores offer the same products. So another store may not have categoryID 128

**The Code:**

```
  st <- unique(Cat4N$StoreID) #there are 3300 unique StoreIDs
                     
                    
                     for (s in 1:length(st)){  # for each StoreID
                      
                      # get a list of unique 3 digit categoryIDs 
                       es <- unique(Cat3N$ctgry [which(Cat3N$StoreID == st[s])]) #there are up to 130 3 digit category numbers and up to 800 4 digit category numbers
                            
                            
                        for (e in 1:length(es)){ #For Each 3 digit Category ID
                            
                            
                                pste <- Cat4N$ctgry[which(substr(Cat4N[,"ctgry"],1,3) == es[e] & Cat4N$StoreID == st[s])] #get a list of the 4 digit Category  ids within the current 3d category number (stored in variable "es") in that specific store (stored in variable "st")
                    
                                        
                                     for (p in 1:length(pste)){#for each 4d category in pste
                                   
                                       #take the row uniquely Identified by StoreID and 4d CategoryID, 
                                                #then Multiply the 3 digit categoryID volume total for that store by the coefficient of ( 4digit category total in that store divided by the sum of all 4d category ID volume in that store)
                                       Cat4N$vol1[which(Cat4N[,"ctgry"] == pste[p] & Cat4N[,"StoreID"] == st[s])] <- 
                                                    Cat3N$vol1[which(Cat3N[,'ctgry'] == es[e] & Cat3N[,'StoreID'] == st[s])] * 
                                                    (Cat4N$vol1[which(Cat4N[,2] == pste[p] & Cat4N[,"StoreID"] == st[s])] / sum(Cat4N$vol1[which(substr(Cat4N[,2],1,3) == es[e] & Cat4N[,"StoreID"] == st[s])]))  
                                       
                                       
                                       Cat4N$vol2[which(Cat4N[,"ctgry"] == pste[p] & Cat4N[,"StoreID"] == st[s])] <- Cat3N$vol2[which(Cat3N[,'ctgry'] == es[e] & Cat3N[,'StoreID'] == st[s])] * (Cat4N$vol2[which(Cat4N[,2] == pste[p] & Cat4N[,"StoreID"] == st[s])]/ sum(Cat4N$vol2[which(substr(Cat4N[,2],1,3) == es[e] & Cat4N[,"StoreID"] == st[s])]))  
                                       Cat4N$vol3[which(Cat4N[,"ctgry"] == pste[p] & Cat4N[,"StoreID"] == st[s])] <- Cat3N$vol3[which(Cat3N[,'ctgry'] == es[e] & Cat3N[,'StoreID'] == st[s])] * (Cat4N$vol3[which(Cat4N[,2] == pste[p] & Cat4N[,"StoreID"] == st[s])]/ sum(Cat4N$vol3[which(substr(Cat4N[,2],1,3) == es[e] & Cat4N[,"StoreID"] == st[s])]))  
                                       
                           }
                           }
                           }
```

Comment: When it finishes running, what does it return?

Comment: It just replaces the current volume numbers in the data set with the fitted numbers